# Jupyter notebook linear regression problem

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science, linear-regression, prediction

in jupyter notebook when we input this we expect this output as shown in screenshot
[image: correct answer]

But in my notebook when i enter same query i am getting different output why[image: wrong output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the fitted model outputs are shown in the newest version of sklearn, i.e., 0.23. The parameters are the same, but they are not shown in the output. To replicate the same you have to downgrade your python < 3.4 and skelarn < 0.23.
There is another way you can check this if you want which is shown below:

[image: Scikit-learn example]